# Python: Why is PillowWriter changing the shape of my gif when I save it?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

I am making a heatmap animation using pyplot.pcolor and mpl.ArtistAnimation. It is resized to aspect ratio 1:1 and the margins are set tight. The animation works fine and is well cropped and sized when I output it in python but when I save it using

```
animation=ArtistAnimation(fig1,list_of_figures,interval=400,repeat_delay=2000,blit=True)
f="c:/animations/myanimation.gif"
writergif=mpl.animation.PillowWriter(fps=10)
animation.save(f,writer=writergif)
```

It saves and maintains aspect ratio fine but with large gaps on the left and right as if trying to meet some standard size. How can this be fixed?

Comment: The images in the animation are 288 by 288 and output in python as such. But when I save it using PillowWriter it changes to 432 by 288. I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

fig.set_size_inches(4.8, 4.8, forward=True)

Just before the save.

This seems to have fixed my issues. I have no idea why because its not on the right end and it was already set to those dimensions. Maybe its something to do with the "forward=True" bit. I don't know but it worked for me.